# Implementing TLS 1.2 when I SSH into a box as a measure against POODLE

Tags: ssh, fedora, openssl, tls, poodle

Is it possible to edit `sshd_config` or `ssh_config`, such that the SSH connection into a machine configured to use TLS1.2 is successful and rejects connections configured to use TLS1.1 and below, as well as SSL3 and below?

Is there any other way to do this?

This is on Fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand something, but it is an easy thing to get confused about.

- SSH = **S**ecure **SH**ell
- SSL = **S**ecure **S**ockets **L**ayer

`ssh`/`sshd` is a standalone client-server application that uses it's own high level protocol (the SSH protocol); SSL is a parallel protocol used with (e.g.) HTTPS servers.  Applications which use one or the other may use the same low level ciphers (which you can delimit with the `Ciphers` option in `sshd_config`), hence `ssh` implementations are generally linked to `libssl` (which actually implements the ciphers<sup>1</sup>), but the high level protocol used for secure shell communication is neither SSL nor TLS.

You can set which versions of the ssh protocol to accept, (see the `Protocol` option in `man sshd_config`) but the default is already the most secure.

---

<sup>1. TBH I'm not positive that's the reason for the linkage, but point being, it's not in order to use the SSL protocol.</sup>

Comment: Thank You Goldilocks. 
So when I give a command at the command line, 
"openssl s_client -connect <HOST:port_number> -<ssl2/ssl3/tls1/tls1_1/tls1_2>"


This pertains to openssl and not SSH ???

Comment: Yep.  `s_client` is "a generic SSL/TLS client which can establish a transparent connection to a remote server speaking SSL/TLS. It's intended for testing purposes only..."

Comment: Thank again Goldilocks. I am fresh out of school and trying to work on a project. I posed similar questions elsewhere but the responses were too rude. Appreciate your patience! 
Adding to the question, so is it not possible from a server POV to limit SSL and enable only TLS1.2 ?? 

I am not sure if I framed my question correctly, but I could do that to lightpd and see that only TLS1.2 based connections were successful and the rest were dropped.

Comment: Web servers can and should have that option, yes.  I'm not a lighttpd user though, so I don't know about that specifically.  I'm sure if you look through the configuration docs you will find something.

Comment: @hack This is off topic, but: was it a Fedora-related site where you got rude responses? If so, please let me know — that's not how we want to treat people.

Comment: mattdm nope not a Fedora-related site. Thanks for that.. 

goldilocks i will keep trying and update it once I have a solution. Thanks a tonne!!

Comment: If the issue is now lightttpd, I would leave that out of this Q&A, things will get too confusing.   This might as well be here -- it wasn't long ago I realized that ssh didn't really use SSL ;)

Answer (score 4):

POODLE is not a problem for SSH.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan! 
I am looking for a way to get TLS working and disable the rest.